# Symmetric Difference of Two Arrays

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, arrays, math, set

I have two `NSArray`s of Movie objects called DVD and VHS. I'd like to find the symmetric difference of these arrays. I want to know which Movies are in VHS buy not in DVD, and which Movies are in DVD but not VHS.

Can anyone tell me if there is a fast algorithm to solve it (preferably in C or Objective-C)? Is it faster/easier to solve if I use Dictionaries? What this kind of problem called (or is it just "Symmetric Difference")?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get better results using `NSSet` rather than `NSArray`, depending on whether or not you want to allow duplicates in your lists.

`NSSet` gives you methods like `intersectsSet:` which should give you what you need.

If you need union functionality, you can use `NSMutableSet`.

Comment: Symmetric difference is `(A union B) minus (A intersect B)`, or equivalently, `(A minus B) union (B minus A)`.

Comment: There are no duplicates in my arrays. `intersectsSet:` seems to only return a `BOOL` telling you whether or not they do intersect. I'm looking for the opposite of an intersection. I looked through the `NSSet` docs, but couldn't see a method like the one I need.

Comment: Note that NSMutableSet has `-intersectSet:` which actually removes objects from the receiver to tranform it into the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

If you need VHS minus DVD, and DVD minus VHS in two different arrays, use `-removeObjectsInArray:`.

If you need them both in the same array, sort them and try to re-implement [this algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference/) in ObjC.

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting both of the arrays using Title of the Movie (MergeSort), then merge both of them and modify the merge function so that it prints unique uncommon elements.

Comment: This sounds close to what I was thinking of. Sort the arrays (I have ids) then step through both arrays at the same time, comparing and finding matches or holes / uncommon elements. Do you know where I can find code for this? Is this called a Merge Sort?

Comment: Yes, it is called NergeSort. You can find lots of example on the net. here is one: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Merge_sort